# access session in php files

Tags: php

I have three files assign_job.php, events.php and edit_cal.php

Now assign_job has a drop down, when i select any item and submit the form, i create a seession as

```
$_SESSION["memberid"] = $_POST['partner'];
```

this gives me the values in the dropdown in the session. I am able to echo it on the same page.

In events.php i have a mysql query whire i need to bind the session as

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = $_SESSION["memberid"]";
```

Now the issue is i am not able to access the session value on events.php. i am using 
`session_start()`; in both the pages.

TIA

Comment: Did you insert into calendar the session id? If so, please show code for that too.

Comment: events.php
session_start();
$memid = $_SESSION["memberid"];

echo $memid;


date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
include("functions/database.functions.php");
global $connection;
// Open database connection
open_database();
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$command = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = $_SESSION["memberid"]";
$result = mysql_query($command, $connection);

Comment: sorry not able to edit it

Comment: I am not inserting session value to database.

Comment: `$command = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = '.$_SESSION["memberid"];`

Comment: wow !!!! its happening now ... thanks .... PHP is a funny language .... beign a .net guy :)

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.  As a .NET guy, you will likely feel right at home with PDO.

Comment: Looks like MySql, you can also use prepared statements with it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
$memid = $_SESSION["memberid"];
echo $memid; 

and so on whatever code you want to write..
```

Above code is for event.php.

ok, **now follow this important note** : DON'T EVER GIVE SPACE OR NEW LINE BEFORE  "`session_start();`" it will be the firstline after php tag at the starting of your page.

and query should be :

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = $_SESSION['memberid']";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the quotes.

```
$command = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = $_SESSION["memberid"]';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
session_start();
$memid = $_SESSION["memberid"];
```

and query like this

```
 $command = 'SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id > 0 and member_id = '.$_SESSION["memberid"];
```